# Save data to localstorage and display it as innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, stack-overflow, angular2-localstorage

I've used these codes for making a simple notes app. It have to store the text box value into localStorage, by pressing the remember button. Then display it but pressing the other button. But it's not working.

```
<HTML>

<head>
    <script>
        function myfunction1() { //remember code var
            texttosave = document.getElementById('textline').innerHTML;
            localStorage.setItem('mynumber', texttosave);
        }

        function
        myfunction2() { //recall code
            document.getElementById('recalledtext').innerHTML =
                localStorage.getItem('mynumber');
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="textline" />
    <button id="rememberer" onclick='myfunction1()'>remember text</button>
    <button id="recaller" onclick='myfunction2()'>recall text </button>
    <p id="recalledtext">Loading</p>
</body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: do you have some error in your console?

Comment: There this same questions. But their answers are not working for me.

Comment: @sheplu I'm new at web scripts. What console are you talking about?

Comment: I just posted the code into "test.html" file and opened it via localhost.

Comment: Do I have to do any other thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<input>` element's `.innerHTML` property doesn't change when you enter text. To see what's currently entered into an inputbox, one must use its `.value` property.

As such

```
texttosave = document.getElementById('textline').innerHTML ;
```

needs to become

```
texttosave = document.getElementById('textline').value ;
```

and that should do it.

You also, later, linked to your testing website. The code there is

```
function myfunction1(){ //remember code texttosave = ..........
```

but that makes `texttosave = ..........` part of the comment. You need to write

```
function myfunction1(){ //remember code
    texttosave = ..........
```

now you've put `texttosave = ......` on a separate line, so it's not considered part of the comment.

Alternatively, if you don't want to insert the line breaks to keep the code concise, remove the comments (`//remember code`, `//recall code`) and then you can keep them on the same line.

Another alternative is to replace the single line comments (e.g. `// remember code`) with a multiline comment that you close on the same line (i.e. `/* remember code */`)